# Qt > very custom tree-like control

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, treeview

I try to built this kind of control in my Qt application.

[image]

Here each `Item` is a parent item for `new` items. `Items` should be able to be dragged and dropped internally, also have expand-collapse feature. Also each `Item` has it's own scrollbar i.e. if child items count exceeds some number a scroll bar should appear per section.

I have found examples, where `QTreeView`'s items are made drag and dropp-able, but I have no idea how should I implement separate scroll-bar part.

Any ideas about which control can be used and how?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It would be easier to implement it as a list of lists rather than a tree. This way each item will have its own view with dedicated scroller.

Comment: @dtech I did some reading again and what if I implement it with using `QTreeWidget` with `QListView`s inside of it? I need to use also `model-view` approach here, because it should be possible to apply some filters on `new` items.

Comment: Why do you even need a tree widget? And when I say "a list of lists", that means list models and list views.So you have nested lists and nested views. The outer list view is the "Item" view which is the header part plus the inner list view for every item.

Comment: @dtech Sorry, I didn't mentioned in my question - I need the headers to have expand-collapse property, that's why I think of a tree-like structure.

Comment: For the last time - you don't need that, if you want to "collapse" an item - just remove or hide its inner list view.

Comment: OK, I've got your point. I will give a try.